# Calabash android hybrid app with IONIC framework. unable to access elements

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to test a hybrid app (created with ionic cordova) with calabash.

I am not able to see any elements in the console. Any query statement returns [] Below is the code snippet of what I did. Let me know what is wrong.

```
D:\ionicProject\todo\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk>calabash-androi
d console android-debug.apk ADB_DEVICE_ARG=emulator-5554
Starting calabash-android console...
Loading C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.15/irbrc
Running irb...
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows

irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background

nil

irb(main):002:0> query("webView css:'*'")

[]

irb(main):003:0> query("CordovaWebView css:'*'")

[]
```

Comment: please add some code, not console output. edit properly and be clear

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `SystemWebView` instead of `CordovaWebView`

Example:

```
query("SystemWebView css:'*'")
```

Answer (score 2):

First simply use `query('*')` and see all the result.

Then find all the element with class using

```
query('*', :class)
```

Then find all the element with class using

```
query('*',:id)
```

If you want to display only text content

```
query('*', :textContent)
```

if you know the correct view `(ie webview or systemview)` You can use that view name instead of `*`